# Django REST: serializer field that isn't a model field

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have two models (and matching Serializers):

```
class Book(models.Model):
   created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   owner = models.ForeignKey(MyUser)
   title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
   author = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')

class ReadBy(models.Model):
   created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   owner = models.ForeignKey(MyUser)
```

When the book has been read it's stored in the ReadBy database. When the user retrieves the books using the Book model/serializer I want a field telling me if that particular user has read the book.

I.e. I would like to add a field to the Model Book (pseudo-code):

```
has_been_read_by = if_exists_in_readby display 'true' else 'false'
```

So I need to check if a record exists in the ReadBy database and then display true or false if so.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The take away is that in a serializer method of your `Book` model, you have access to `context` which provides `context['request'].user` and `obj` which represents the `Book` object

I will assume your `ReadBy` has an FK to `Book`, otherwise it's not clear how you link them together

```
class ReadBy(models.Model):
   created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   owner = models.ForeignKey(MyUser)
   book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
```

Let's make a `BookSerializer`

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Book

    has_been_read_by = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_has_been_read_by')

    def get_has_been_read_by(self, obj):
        user = self.context['request'].user
        book = obj

        # See if a ReadBy object exists
        return ReadBy.objects.filter(book=book, owner=user).exists()
```

That field will contain either `True` or `False`, as booleans, which will be translated to your REST format, e.g. JSON (or you can return `true` and `false` strings just as easily)

Now use it in your `ViewSet` e.g.

```
class BookViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    model = Book
    serializer_class = BookSerializer
```

Comment: I cannot figure out how to "Read" the book. If I try to do a POST to add a ReadBy it tells me I need to specify book_id:

1048, "Column 'book_id' cannot be null"

When I specify the book_id it tells me the same. I.e. it seems try Django trys to add that field automatically but fails.

Comment: @Henrik I think that part depends on whatever serializer you are using for the `ReadBy`, e.g. it may expect a full `book` field with the POST, or it may accept just an ID. Hard to tell without the code, if you make a question I'll be happy to have a look!

Comment: OK thanks. I did so. I hope it's understandable :-)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32466973/cannot-post-entry-specifying-specific-id-if-the-id-is-specified-as-foreignkey-in